# Extracting time from Sys.time

Tags: r, time

I have a question that I think stems from my lack of understanding about the nature of the `Sys.time()` output. I want to save output from R with a timestamp in the filename. I tried using `%>%` and `gsub()` but didn't get the expected result.

When I run Sys.time, this is output:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2018-07-02 21:57:27 CDT"
```

When I run the code I think should work, this happens:

```
> Sys.time() %>% gsub("^[^\\s]+\\s([^\\s]+)\\s[^\\s]+$", "\\1", .)
[1] "2018-07-02 21:57:27"
```

Interestingly, this code yields the value I want:

```
> Sys.time() %>% gsub("^[^\\s]+\\s", "", .)
[1] "21:57:27"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can do this with `format` `format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@akrun, thank you, that works!

I also realized the issue. Even though `Sys.time()` prints `"2018-07-02 21:57:27 CDT"` that's just formatting. `"2018-07-02 22:16:45"` is the actual character string.

```
> as.character(Sys.time())
[1] "2018-07-02 22:16:45"
```

This also explains why my second `gsub()` code worked, since there is only one whitespace character in the `Sys.time()` output.

```
> Sys.time() %>% gsub("^[^\\s]+\\s", "", .)
[1] "21:57:27"
```